Springboot data JPA in a module @Entity Not a managed type
been trying to work out why all-day, lots of reading and changes made but zero progress.
I have a database module that has an class marked with @Entiy like this:
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "company_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "addr1")
    private String adress1;

    @Column(name = "addr2")
    private String adress2;

    @Column(name = "addr3")
    private String adress3;

    @Column(name = "addr4")
    private String adress4;

    @Column(name = "postcode")
    private String postcode;
}

and a repository
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
    List<Company> findByName(String companyName);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE LOWER(c.name) LIKE LOWER(concat('%', :name,'%'))")
    List<Company> findByNameLike(@Param("name") String name);
}

and a service because I will have more classes and repositories thus
@Service
public class DatabaseService {
    private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseService(CompanyRepository companyRepository) {
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    public List<Company> findByName(String companyName) {
        return companyRepository.findByName(companyName);
    }

    public List<Company> findByNameLike(String companyName) {
        return companyRepository.findByNameLike(companyName);
    }
}

Initially, these were in sub packages but one possible solution I read was to put them all in the same package which is how they are now.
I even tried moving it all out of the module into the main app but same problem.
Being dyslexic I have spent a great deal of time going over the code checking each character of each word, no errors in case or sequence i.e. if spelt wrong then consistently spelt wrong.
The database model gradle file
plugins {
    java
    idea
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
}

group = "co.uk.myapp"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

val lombokVersion = "1.18.30"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation( "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.2")
    implementation( "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.1.0")

    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

The main project gradle file only differs in the dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":database"))

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-core")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: "Management App"
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  thymeleaf:
  cache: false
  datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5000/management
  username: user_man
  password:
  statement-cache-size: 250
  statement-cache-sql-limit: 2048
  hikari:
    pool-name: MyHikariPool
    connection-timeout: 30000
    maximum-pool-size: 10
    minimum-idle: 5
    idle-timeout: 600000
    max-lifetime: 1800000   

Must have done something stupid but I cant see it!
Found the edit link :)
Main class
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"co.uk.training", "co.uk.training.management" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {CompanyRepository.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"co.uk.training.database.entity"})
public class TrainingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TrainingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

The log goes over the 3000-character limit

could you show me some error log, or just the whole output when your application starting ?

please share your project structure, main spring class (one annotated with @SpringBootApplication) and error logs

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"co.uk.training", "co.uk.training.management" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {CompanyRepository.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"co.uk.training.database.entity"})
public class TrainingApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(TrainingApplication.class, args);
}
}

What is the package of Company class?

Application fails to start
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepository' defined in co.uk.training.database.CompanyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TrainingApplication: Not a managed type: class co.uk.training.database.Company

You are only scanning co.uk.training.database.entity, not co.uk.training.database via @EntityScan

By default, Spring searches for entities and repositories below the same package of your main class. So if your applciation has a standard structure (if not please share it), you don't need all that stuff annotations scanBasePackages , EnableJpaRepositories, EntityScan, etc., a simple @SpringBootApplication should do the job. Also just for information @Autowired is not needed anymore on your service constructor since Spring 4.3 if you have a single constructor.

I have been trying a lot of variations on the project. The stupid mistake I made was misspelling the PackagesToScan in the entity manager bean. Lost count of how many times called like that!

Try adding @EntityScan("com.entity.package") on main class.

One of the first things I tried with various packages upto and including the package the class is in :(
